# Floating Point Error Safe for Vector = Vector in C++

Tags: c++

Getting an error after validating.

Check if two TVECTOR's are equal to each other

IN:        v       First Vector
        w       Second Vector

RETURN:  True if v==w, False otherwise

NOTE:  Use's all four components
            Should be floating point error safe.

```
bool Vector_IsEqual(TVECTOR v, TVECTOR w)
{

    for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
    {
        if( ( float ) v.e[ i ] == ( float ) w.e[ i ] ) {
            return true;
        }

        else {
        return false;
        }
    }
}

Inputs:
    < -2,  0, -4,  1 >
    < -2,  1.9999999e-005, -4,  1 >
Your output:
    true
Correct output:
    false
```

Comment: Yes, but you've neglected to give us its definition.  Please read http://sscce.org.

Comment: its really irreverent but here ya go: typedef union TVECTOR
{
 // array access to vector elements
 float e[4];

 // individual component access
 struct  
 {
  float x,y,z,w;
 };
}*LPTVECTOR;

Comment: anyone know how to do this that actually knows something about Vectors?

Comment: My answer explains what is wrong with your code.  If your code still doesn't work, then you need to update your question to explain the new problem.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest looking very carefully at the code inside your loop.  Will it ever reach the 2nd iteration?

Comment: Also, that's probably not the best way to compare floating point values for equality.

Comment: @JoshLake no it won't. It exits the loop (and returns from the function) when you find the first equal items.

Comment: @TamásSzelei It depends (the "probably" is definitely misplaced). I'd expect a compound of imprecise floats to behave the same way as an individual imprecise float, rather than behave true to some weird tolerance arithmetic. That aside, equality can (or even must) sometimes be the best idea for comparing floats.

Comment: Rest of the inputs are fine, just when the input is a float is when it crashes

Comment: How can I return if its true or not without returning inside the loop?

Comment: @Josh: As soon as there's a mismatch, you can return `false` immediately.  Otherwise, you need to wait until the loop has finished before you can return `true`.

Comment: I was doing that but then the last input failed the check.  Inputs:
  < -2,  0, -4,  1 >
  < -2,  0, -4,  1.000005 >

Comment: @Josh: Then you'll need to edit your question to include the *exact* code you were using, along with *exact* input.

Comment: @Josh: I mean "copy and paste so that it compiles and demonstrates the problem".

Comment: spread out over a few files and an already compiled program does the check. Here is the link to the test.cpp with the inputs. http://ideone.com/TvUkK Like I stated above, they do not equal like they should.

Comment: @Josh: If you can't provide us with code that we can simply compile and run, it's going to be tricky to spot the problem.